# How to get path of the upload file from swagger?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iformfile

I was following this post https://dejanstojanovic.net/aspnet/2021/april/handling-file-upload-in-aspnet-core-5-with-swagger-ui/ to learn how to upload files with swagger but I have a problem with files path.

I upload a file and it alaways send me a FileNotFoundException because IFormFile doesn't gives me path of file, it gives me only name. How can I get full path?

My code is dummy because I just get blocked on this issue but here it is:

```
        public void Import(IFormFile file)
        {
            XSSFWorkbook book;
            try
            {
                using (FileStream f = new FileStream(file.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    book = new XSSFWorkbook(f);
                }
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The file or directory cannot be found.");
            }

        }
```

Thank you!

Comment: Shouldn't you just use [`IFormFile.OpenReadStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.iformfile.openreadstream?view=aspnetcore-6.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-http-iformfile-openreadstream) rather than constructing `FileStream` instance?

Comment: It worked! Could you explain to me why?

Comment: Because `IFormFile` is an interface that abstracts away details on how exactly the file is being delivered. You can check out [the tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-6.0) to see that it's possible to stream the files directly, without the server persisting them in temporary storage first.